# List all available cars for a given date SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hello guys am trying to show list of all available cars for a given date i try with `BETWEEN` but unsuccessfully. 
Is it a good idea to add another field(status) in the car table and query with status. Has there's a good approach? Or is it better to be displayed by using the booking_date between return_date?

**booking:**

```
    id  customer_id  car_id  booking_date  return_date  time_stamp      
------  -----------  ------  ------------  -----------  ----------------
     1            2       5  2015-11-04    2015-11-12   15.06.10 20:10  
     2            3       2  2015-11-02    2015-11-13   15.06.10 20:10  
     3            1      11  2015-11-05    2015-11-16   15.06.10 20:10  
     4            4       8  2015-11-10    2015-12-16   15.06.10 20:10  
     5            0       0  0000-00-00    0000-00-00   15.06.10 20:10
```

**CarType:**

```
   id  car_type_id  branch_id  registration_number  color    date_of_manifacturing  base_price_per_day  
------  -----------  ---------  -------------------  -------  ---------------------  --------------------
     1            1          1  BG-123-431           Bela     2010-11-15                               30
     2            2          1  BG-A32-212           Metalik  2015-11-04                               30
     3            3          2  PA-332-421           Metalik  2008-05-03                               35
     4            4          1  SM-312-542           Crna     2014-06-01                               35
     5            5          1  BG-4393-54           Crna     2012-05-03                               50
     6            6          1  NS-423-64            Bela     2010-10-08                               50
```

**Car:**

```
   id  car_type_id  branch_id  registration_number  color    date_of_manifacturing  base_price_per_day  
------  -----------  ---------  -------------------  -------  ---------------------  --------------------
     1            1          1  BG-123-431           Bela     2010-11-15                               30
     2            2          1  BG-A32-212           Metalik  2015-11-04                               30
     3            3          2  PA-332-421           Metalik  2008-05-03                               35
     4            4          1  SM-312-542           Crna     2014-06-01                               35
     5            5          1  BG-4393-54           Crna     2012-05-03                               50
     6            6          1  NS-423-64            Bela     2010-10-08                               50
```

My all bookings am listing like this:

```
SELECT BOOKING.BOOKING_NUMBER, BOOKING.BOOKING_DATE,
BOOKING.RETURN_DATE, AGENCY.NAME, CAR.REGISTRATION_NUMBER,
CAR_TYPE.NAME
FROM BOOKING
JOIN AGENCY ON BOOKING.AGENCY_ID = AGENCY.ID
JOIN CAR ON CAR.ID = BOOKING.CAR_ID
JOIN CAR_TYPE ON CAR_TYPE.ID = CAR.CAR_TYPE_ID
```

But for all available vehicles I have no idea.
Any example?

Answer (score 1):

Using your `booking` table you can know what cars are book on a single day `@checkDate`

```
SELECT *
FROM BOOKING
WHERE @checkDate BETWEEN booking_date  AND return_date
```

So to get available cars on that date, you use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars 
WHERE car_id not in (
                      SELECT car_id
                      FROM BOOKING
                      WHERE @checkDate BETWEEN booking_date  AND return_date  
                     )
```

OR in your full query

```
SELECT 
      BOOKING.BOOKING_NUMBER, BOOKING.BOOKING_DATE,
      BOOKING.RETURN_DATE, AGENCY.NAME, 
      CAR.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, CAR_TYPE.NAME
FROM BOOKING
JOIN AGENCY ON BOOKING.AGENCY_ID = AGENCY.ID
JOIN CAR ON CAR.ID = BOOKING.CAR_ID
JOIN CAR_TYPE ON CAR_TYPE.ID = CAR.CAR_TYPE_ID
WHERE
    CAR.car_id not in (
                        SELECT car_id
                        FROM BOOKING
                        WHERE @checkDate BETWEEN booking_date  AND return_date  
                      )
```

Comment: I think for the bigger amount of data `NOT IN` is litle slower? Beeter to use `NOT EXIST`

Comment: I just give you the safest solution. You can also try  `left join BOOKING on @checkDate BETWEEN booking_date  AND return_date` but because I dont have the data didnt want to guess. That way you will get `NULL` for `not booked ` cars

Comment: I think will work ok if you have index for `booking_date and return_date`. Other solution is use `EXISTS` but you will know what is the better only by testing with your data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  CAR.REGISTRATION_NUMBER,
  CAR_TYPE.NAME,
  AGENCY.NAME, 
  CASE 
    WHEN BOOKING.CAR_ID IS NULL THEN 'Not Booked' 
    ELSE 'Booked' 
  END AS Status,
  BOOKING.BOOKING_NUMBER, 
  BOOKING.BOOKING_DATE,
  BOOKING.RETURN_DATE
FROM CAR
INNER JOIN CAR_TYPE ON CAR_TYPE.ID      = CAR.CAR_TYPE_ID
LEFT JOIN BOOKING  ON CAR.ID            = BOOKING.CAR_ID
LEFT JOIN AGENCY   ON BOOKING.AGENCY_ID = AGENCY.ID;
```

This will give you all the available cars, and if any cars has no booking it will come with `NULL` values for booking and agency, and the `Status` column will show whether it is booking or not.